# Java hashmap search keys for a date

Tags: java, search, key, hashmap

I have a hashmap:
Map dateEvent = new HashMap(); where key is a date and time and value is a string.
I fill collection with data where date is in format dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm.
How I can get all keys with date based on this format: dd.MM.yyyy?

Comment: I hope you are using generics and you have forgotten to write it here. Don't ever use raw types.

Comment: When you say key is a date and time do you mean a `Date` object or a `String` object in the form `dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261237/sort-keys-which-are-date-entries-in-a-hashmap this may help you. It's not the exact case as yours but there is a useful code with the Date as a key.

Comment: What do you mean by "date based on this format: dd.MM.yyyy" ? All your keys are of same  format right ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code will do the trick:

```
public static void findEvents(Map<Date, Event> dateEvents, Date targetDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    String target = dateFormat.format(targetDate); 
    for (Map.Entry<Date, Event> entry : dateEvents.entrySet()) {
        if (dateFormat.format(entry.getKey()).equals(target)) {
            System.out.println("Event " + entry.getValue() + " is on the specified date");
        }
    }
}
```

The important thing here is that all dates are converted to a String with format "dd.MM.yyyy" before comparing, so any differences in hour/minute/second still match if the day is the same.

This code also demonstrates the best way (IMHO) to iterate over a map.

Comment: If you need both key and value this sure is the best way to iterate over a map. Code analyzers such as FindBugs will note this too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether I get you right. However, you get the set of keys from a map using `map.keySet()`. If you want to find all different dates fill all dates into a set. If you want to reduce the accuracy to days, one solution would be to convert the date to the desired format and add those strings to a set. Duplicates will be removed automatically.

E.g.:

```
Map<Date, String> yourMap = [..];

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

Set<String> differentDates = new HashSet<String>();
for (Date date: yourMap.keySet()) {
    differentDates.add(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) two options:

You could write your own Date class which supplies appropriate implementations of `hashCode()` and `equals()`. (If you do this, it is not recommended that you base that class on another class that already defines these methods (e.g. `java.util.Date`).)

The brute force alternative is to scan all keys whether they fit your criteria.

Comment: "(If you do this, it is not recommended that you base that class on another class that already defines these methods (e.g. java.util.Date).)" why?

Comment: @Dejel Pretty sure this goes against the contract. [`java.util.Date#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) states the two dates have to be equal to the millisecond in order to be equal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between between the Date `01.01.2011`*(dd.MM.yyyy)* and the Date `01.01.2011 00:00`(*dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm)*.

`Date` holds a `long` which has hours and minutes. Even for `public Date(int year, int month, int date)`